# Creating a new column based on the condition of others

Tags: r

Still very new to coding and R, I am working with some healthcare data in a data frame.  There are 3 outcomes that I am interested in - `Mobilised_D1`, `Diet_D1` and `Catheter_rm_D1`.  I wish to create a fourth column called `AnyTwo` whereby if any 2 of the 3 outcomes are `Y` or all three outcomes are `Y`, then it will be `T` for `AnyTwo`.

I've managed to do this by using `[]` as below:

````
ERAS_limited[ERAS_limited$Mobilised_D1 == "Y" & ERAS_limited$Catheter_rm_D1 == "Y", "AnyTwo"] <- T
ERAS_limited[ERAS_limited$Diet_D1 == "Y" & ERAS_limited$Catheter_rm_D1 == "Y", "AnyTwo"] <- T
ERAS_limited[ERAS_limited$Diet_D1 == "Y" & ERAS_limited$Catheter_rm_D1 == "Y" & ERAS_limited$Mobilised_D1 == "Y", "AnyTwo"] <- T

dput(head(ERAS_limited))
structure(list(Mobilised_D1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Diet_D1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    Catheter_rm_D1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), AnyTwo = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")```
````

However, I would be keen to see if there is a more elegant way of doing this e.g. by writing a loop for my own education and curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to create the logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
ERAS_limited %>% 
    mutate(AnyTwo = rowSums(.[-4] == "Y")  >= 2)
```

---

In `base R`, it would be

```
ERAS_limited$AnyTwo <- rowSums(ERAS_limited[-4]) == "Y") >= 2
```

Comment: That's brilliant, so, so simple now that you've shown me, thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks it is accepted. I know the solution is very simple but just for my own curiosity, is it possible to do this another way by writing some sort of for and if loop?

Comment: @LarryLi  Yes you can loop through the columns with a `for` loop and get a logical vector while adding it in each loop, then check whether it is greater than or equal to 2

Comment: Thanks, can you show me how it would look?  I am really new to this.

Comment: @LarryLi One option is `v1 <- numeric(nrow(ERAS_limited));for(j in 1:3)  v1 <- v1 + (ERAS_limited[[j]] == "Y"); ERAS_limited$AnyTwo <- v1 >=2`